# $Y$ have the pdf $g ( x ) = \frac { S ( x ) } { \mu } \mathbb{1} _ { \{ x > 0 \} }$. Find the expected value of $Y$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a positive continuous random variable with mean $\mu$,
> variance $\sigma ^ { 2 }$ and survival function $S(x)$ for $x > 0$.
>
> $g ( x ) = \frac { S ( x ) } { \mu } \mathbb{1} _ { \{ x > 0 \} }$
>
> Suppose $Y$ is a continuous random variable having the probability
> density function $g$. Find the expected value of $Y$ in terms of $\mu$
> and $\sigma ^ { 2 }$.

I'm only able to show $g$ is a valid probability density function. How can I compute $E(Y)$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please read the description of the tag '[distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)'. It's about [Schwartz distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)), a kind of generalized functions, not about probability distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$EX^{p}=\int_0^{\infty} pt^{p-1} P(X>t)dt$$ for any $p\geq 1$ and any positive random variable $X$. [This is a standard application of Fubini's Theorem]. In  particular $$EX^{2}=\int_0^{\infty} 2t P(X>t)dt.$$ Now you see that $$EY=\int_0^{\infty} xg(x)dx=\frac {EX^{2}} {2\mu}=\frac {\mu^{2}+\sigma^{2}} {2\mu}.$$